# Encrypt connectionString attribute of connectionStrings section

Tags: c#, sql-server, encryption, connection-string

System at my hotel has connection string like this in exe.config file. Now we want to move our database server but we can't because of this. I want to know if this kind of encrypt can be achieve using any defaul encrypt technique or is it a custom one? (*We can't contact the original developer since the company went bankrupt)

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="connectionString" connectionString="XWsoQ6X8Cb3oNDHUPlwKa9XOZgYXxk40iHBtYOy9GgPNKUmQkezt4HFqGYTZfUILtYFi5FA2gzw1DqnbKW3G858uFEpbSTRTYt/OP16Y5cs=" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Search across the source code for "FromBase64String", and add that line and the surroundings to your question.

Comment: @Martheen haha, I tried decoding from Base64 and it looked like gibberish though.

Comment: @Poosh Which is why I ask for the actual code where it decode it from Base64, it may run it through an AES or XOR for all we know.

Comment: @Martheen, sorry, that was a good suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to encrypt connections strings is with aspnet_regiis.exe, and that isn't it.

If I were attempting what you're seeing (as a developer), I'd probably use machine key encryption and decrypt for application use in a static config class.

Does your .config file have a `<machineKey>` element? If so, you may be able to decrypt the connection string using that key.